# Where do the "îs" and "îi" forms of "a fi" ( "to be" ) originate in dialectal Romanian?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, historical-linguistics, dialects, romanian

perhaps the Latin first person singular indicative "sum" with an "î" of uncertain origin? Im not sure about "îi". I guess from the short "e" /je/ form of "este".

Comment: The Latin 1sg pres. subj. of "to be" is *sim*, not *su*.

Comment: my bad, I was thinking of the indicative form actually yet I still got it wrong even so. I think I had in mind a reconstructed vulgar latin/proto-Romanian form.

Comment: What forms are those? They don’t appear in the conjugation table on Wiktionary, so I’m guessing they don’t exist at all in standard Romanian…

Comment: Yes, SarruKen, please explain where those frorms occur and what parts of _a fi_ they are.

Comment: "formă populară de ind. prez. a verbului a fi. Eu îs...; ei / ele îs... – V. fi [DEX'98]
temporarîs

î́s și -s, prescurtare din sînt cînd nu e accentuat, ca: îs aicĭ, nu-s aicĭ"  - https://dexonline.net/definitie-îs   - according to this dictionary they come from the unstressed standard forms ( sînt, este ). But I wanted to hear more opinions on this, because I cant find any other source.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct on both accounts: *(i)este : (i)e : -i : îi*, and *sînt : -s : îs*.